# Sharepoint 2010 custom content type does not show in list creation screen

Tags: sharepoint-2010, contenttype

I have a content type that was created by another developer long ago. After deployment, the content type does not show up in the list creation screen. Even when filtering lists and custom types. It's just not there anywhere. The feature is successfully deployed and if I do a template of the list from another farm, and then create the list from that template everything works as expected.

Thanks for anyone that knows what I might be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that it needs to have a list definition added to the project.